# Sapui5 Swipecontent in Listitem

Tags: sapui5, swipe, listitem

i want to have an ItemList, where a Button appears, when the user swipes the element.

I have this code in my view.xml:

```
    <content>
        <List id="searchResultList" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto" items="{ path : 'assets>/Assets' }">
            <items>
                <ObjectListItem title="{assets>AssetId}">
                    <swipeContent>
                        <Button text="Delete Item" type="Reject"/>
                    </swipeContent>
                </ObjectListItem>
            </items>
        </List>
    </content>
```

But i getting the error: Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/m/swipeContent.js'

What i am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `swipeContent` is an aggregation of `List`, not of `ObjectListItem`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <List id="searchResultList" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto" items="{ path : 'assets>/Assets' }">
            <ObjectListItem title="{assets>AssetId}"/>
            <swipeContent>
                <Button text="Delete Item" type="Reject"/>
            </swipeContent>
    </List>
```

You have the swipeContent inside of the ObjectListItem control, therefore doesn't works.

[JS Bin Demonstration](https://jsbin.com/vuqiti/6/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This won't work either; `swipeContent` should be on same level as `items`

Comment: Sorry my mistake... if you remove the <items> tag, will works. See my edited answer with JS Bin Demonstration.